# Borg pattern unexpected behaviour when used in two different modules

Tags: python, import

I am using the Borg pattern with mutual inclusion of modules. See the example code (not the real code but it shows the problem) below. In this case, I have two different Borgs because the class names (and I guess the class) are seen as different by the interpreter.

Is there a way to use the Borg in that case without reworking the module architecture?

Module `borg.py`

```
import borg2

class Borg:
    _we_are_one = {}

    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = Borg._we_are_one
        try:
            self.name
        except AttributeError:
            self.name = "?"
        print self.__class__, id(self.__dict__)

def fct_ab():
    a = Borg()
    a.name = "Bjorn"

    b = Borg()
    print b.name

if __name__ == "__main__":
    fct_ab()
    borg2.fct_c()
```

Module `borg2.py`

```
import borg

def fct_c():
    c = borg.Borg()
    print c.name
```

The result is

```
__main__.Borg 40106720
__main__.Borg 40106720
Bjorn
borg.Borg 40106288
?
```

In order to clarify my problem:
Why does Python consider `__main__.Borg` and `borg.Borg` as two different classes?

Comment: Do you actually have mutual imports?  Does borg2 import borg?  Does borg import borg2?  Why do you have these mutual imports?

Comment: In fact, I don't have these mutual imports but I succeed to simulate my problems like this. I have 2 modules which are importing the same module but which see them with different names.

Comment: What's the actual use-case for a bunch of instances that all share the same state/`__dict__`? The only thing that differentiates them is their id() (and perhaps `__slots__` if they have them.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem only occurs in your main-function. Move that code
to its own file and everything is as you'd expect. This code

```
import borg
import borg2

if __name__ == "__main__":
    borg.fct_ab()
    borg2.fct_c()
```

delivers this output:

```
borg.Borg 10438672
borg.Borg 10438672
Bjorn
borg.Borg 10438672
Bjorn
```

Comment: It works but I would have to rework my module architecture. A bit more complex in my real app.

Comment: I've accepted the answer which is ok for the question i've asked.

Answer (score 4):

After a long day of struggling with Singletons and Borg, my conclusion is the following:

It seems that a Python module imported multiple times using different 'import paths' is actually imported multiple times. If that module contains a singleton, you get multiple instances.

Example:

```
myproject/
  module_A
  some_folder/
    module_B
    module_C
```

If module_A imports module_C using `from myproject.some_folder import module_C` and module_B imports the same module_C using `import module_C`, the module is actually imported twice (at least according to my observations). Usually, this doesn't matter, but for singletons or borg, you actually get 2 instances of what should be unique. (That's 2 sets of borgs sharing 2 different internal states).

Solution: Give yourself an import statement convention and stick to it: I import all modules starting from a common root folder, even if the module file is located parallel to the one I am working on, so in the example above, both module_A and module_B import module_C using `from myproject.some_folder import module_C`.

Answer (score 1):

It's not the class names that is the problem. I'm not entirely sure why Python see the Borg class and the borg.Borg class as different, perhaps it's because you run this from `__main__`, I think python does not realize that `__main__` and borg is the same module.

The solution is easy. Change fct_ab to:

```
def fct_ab():
    import borg
    a =  borg.Borg()
    a.name = "Bjorn"

    b = borg.Borg()
    print b.name
```

This solves the problem.

Comment: It doesn't make any difference in my case :-(

Comment: Well, in any case the accepted answer is a cleaner way of doing it.

Answer (score 0):

I've fixed the issue in my real application by fixing an error in the import.

In fact, I have two different modules using the same 3rd module.

The 1st one was importing mypackage.mymodule while the 2nd one was importing mymodule. mypackage is installed as a python egg and the code I was working on is on my development folder.

So both codes were importing different modules and I guess that it is normal to have two different classes in this case.

Regarding the example code I've used, the problem comes from the current modules to receive the **main** as name. I've tried to rename by doing `__name__ = 'borg'`. It works but it breaks the `if __name__ == "__main__"` condistion. As a conclusion, I would say that mutual inclusion must be avoid and is in most cases not necessary.

Thanks all for your help.

Answer (score 0):

The solution --- as has already been mentioned --- is to avoid a recursive `import` of the main module, but `borg.py` is *not* being "imported twice".  The problem is that importing it *at all* while it is already executing causes you define the `Borg` class twice, in two different namespaces.

To demonstrate, I added a few lines to the top of both `borg.py` and `borg2.py`, and inserted my `print_module` function before and after most points of interest:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python2

from __future__ import print_function

def print_module(*args, **kwargs):
    print(__name__ + ':  ', end='')
    print(*args, **kwargs)
    return

print_module('Importing module borg2...')
import borg2
print_module('Module borg2 imported.')

print_module('Defining class Borg...')
class Borg:
    ...
# etc.
```

The output is:

```
__main__:  Importing module borg2...
borg2:  Importing module borg...
borg:  Importing module borg2...
borg:  Module borg2 imported.
borg:  Defining class Borg...
borg:  id(_we_are_one) = 17350480
borg:  Class Borg defined.
borg:  id(Borg) = 139879572980464
borg:  End of borg.py.
borg2:  Module borg imported.
borg2:  End of borg2.py.
__main__:  Module borg2 imported.
__main__:  Defining class Borg...
__main__:  id(_we_are_one) = 17351632
__main__:  Class Borg defined.
__main__:  id(Borg) = 139879572981136
__main__:  Borg 17351632
__main__:  Borg 17351632
__main__:  Bjorn
borg:  Borg 17350480
borg2:  ?
__main__:  End of borg.py.
```

The first thing `borg.py` does (not counting the bits I added) is import `borg2` into the `__main__` namespace.  This happens before the `Borg` class is defined anywhere.

The first thing `borg2` does is import `borg`, which again attempts to import `borg2`... and Python refuses to do so.  (Note that *nothing* happens between lines 3 and 4.)  `borg` finally defines the `Borg` class and the `fct_ab` function in the `borg` namespace, and exits.

`borg2` then defines `fct_c` and exits ("borg2:  End of borg2.py.").  All the `import` statements are done.

Now, `borg.py` *finally* gets to execute "for real".  Yes, it already ran once when it was imported, but this is still the "first" time through the `borg.py` file.  The `Borg` class gets defined again, this time in the `__main__` namespace, and both the class and its dictionary have new IDs.

`borg.py` was not "imported twice".  It was executed once from the command line, and it was executed once when it was imported.  Since these happened in two different namespaces, the "second" definition of `Borg` did not replace the first, and the two functions modified two different classes, which just happened to be created from the same code.